# Button to trigger jQuery to grab HTML and save to database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have some jQuery that when you click the save button it triggers a function to grab the HTML matching a selector and post the HTML to save_report.php:

```
function saveReport() {
  $.post('save_report.php', function(data) {
    $('.report').html(data);
  });
}

$('.save').click(function () {
  saveReport();
});
```

In save_report.php I want to know how i can then save that string to my db.

```
$report = $_POST[''];  # <-- not sure how to post

mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("INSERT INTO reports (id, report) VALUES('', $report) ")
  or die(mysql_error());
```

How do I retrieve the POST value in my php file?

Thanks

Comment: I added the `php` tag as this isn't really a jQuery question

Comment: I made an edit to clean up your code a bit and re-worded some things to make use of more appropriate terms. (For clarity's sake)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things wrong here... The posted code doesn't actually post any data, and the post and html functions are called incorrectly.

So, first I'll grab the html from the .report selector, and store it in a variable.  Then I'll post it providing a variable name of 'report'.  I added a simple callback that alerts what the web server sends back, which you can remove or change.

```
function saveReport() { 
  var data = $('.report').html();
  $.post('save_report.php', {'report':data}, function(response) { alert(response); }); 
}  

$('.save').click(function () { saveReport(); });
```

In your PHP, you would be looking for $_POST['report'] which is how I named the data being posted.

You're not sanitizing any of the input, so basically any random hacker could take over your entire database with SQL injection.  At a minimum, after getting $_POST['report'], run it through the mysql_real_escape_string() function.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you need to change your jQuery code to

```
function saveReport() {
   $.post('save_report.php', {report: $('.report').html(data)} );
}
```

and php to

```
$report = $_POST['report'];  **<-- not sure how to post**

mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("INSERT INTO reports
(id, report) VALUES('', '".mysql_real_escape_string($report)."' ) ") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

Please don't forget to escape the HTML before you put it in your insert query. What you're doing has the potential to go very wrong very fast. I've modified your save_report.php code to fit Fosco's answer. I am now passing the 'optional' `$link` parameter to all of the [`mysql_*`](http://www.php.net/mysql) functions because in general it is a best practice to do so. I've also added some escaping of the value before it is used in your `INSERT` query; It is important to pass the `$link` parameter to the [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) function so it can properly escape the value.

```
$report = $_POST['report'];

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database", $link) or die(mysql_error());

$report = mysql_real_escape_string($report, $link);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO reports (id, report) VALUES('', '{$report}')", $link)
  or die(mysql_error());
```